# bash "reflection"

Tags: bash

in java we call it reflection.  but basically, i have a variable in my bash script

```
buildvar=dev
```

now, my script is a menu driven system.  so in the menu of my script i want to be able to type in something like

```
changevar buildvar=prod
```

and have my script update the variable with the new value.  the changevar command is easy enough in my script, but how do i get it to realize that the buildvar is a variable name and to update that variable?

Comment: With copious use of `eval` I imagine.

Comment: BTW the term is 'variable variables'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you can parse the command. the rest is:

```
a=varname
b=value
eval $a=$b
echo $varname
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is add this line to your script:

```
alias changevar='export'
```

But that depends on how do you use your `menu`...